# Como fazer um split de uma coluna do tipo DateTime vinda de uma consulta pelo Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Possuo um campo do tipo `DateTime?` (nulo permitido) que está no formado de data/hora completa (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss).

Preciso exibir a data e a hora em colunas separadas em um datagridview. Tentei usar o `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Data.Value.Date)` conforme vi em sugestões daqui, porém dá o seguinte erro:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'

Comment: `dataGridView` é winforms ?

Comment: Acho que o problema é só na exibição... não precisa mexer nos dados... coloca o código de como você está carregando / exibindo isso que vai ajudar a resolver

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Fui editar a pergunta e percebi isso também. Se for o caso, me sinalize para que eu apague a resposta, por favor.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, isso. winforms. Obrigado pela ajuda, pessoal.

Comment: coloque o código que você popula a datagridview então, e se você gera as colunas pela ferramenta visual ou via código

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você tem que usar a função de apoio [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime.aspx). Para usar esta função você precisa passar o  `DateTime` completo, não o membro `Date`

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Data)
```

Comment: Thanks, @LINQ. Funcionou :)